# WebDriverWait until element to be clickable, how to timeout when page fully loaded?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using the below code to wait for an element to be clickable. However I'd really like it to timeout as soon as the page fully loads without the element being found, instead of waiting a number of seconds. Is that possible?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, id_var)))
```

Comment: Selenium is by nature dumb. From your question it seems that you are trying to build a `is_page_load_complete` kind of function. For that you can either depend on explicit waits(there are lots of option to choose from, not just clickable) or look at fluent wait capability of selenium. In case if that also does not resolve your situation, then you will have to implement a `while True: if <condition satisfies>: break, else: continue` kind of loop

Comment: If your page does not use ajax and node js you can also look at this javascrpit snippet `document.readyState`. On successful load completion, it should return `complete`. you can utilise this fact in your custom made function as well

Comment: Thank you but if I wasn't explaining clearly, I want to wait as short amount as time as possible until the element is clickable, but I want the timeout to happen when the page is fully loaded. Or are you saying to do something like while not readyState and then use an if condition to check for the existence of the element? I'm not sure how to use a javascript snippet though to return a value the same way as a function though? How would that work?

Comment: If I understood correctly we want the timeout to happen whenever the page is loaded completely or the element is found, whichever is earlier. if that is the case, yes we can implement something like you mentioned. `driver.execute_script("return document.readyState;")` should return `complete` or `driver.execute_script("return document.readyState=='complete';")` should return `True`

Comment: Got it, thank you so much.